# Querying to DB in MVC 5 App

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am teaching myself how to create a pretty extensive app that is database heavy.  And from tutorials that I watch I see examples like this:

```
    follower.MenuItems.Where(m => !MenuItemID.Contains(m.MenuItemID)).ToList()
```

But I don't know how or why this works the way it does.  And since I don't know what this is, I have no idea what to search for tutorial-wise.  So all I am really looking for is for someone to post a tutorial, and/or post other possible ways to query a DB.

Secondary question:  I also want to learn more about proper DB designs, so maybe a well known tutorial on that as well?  Should I be using LINQ?

Sorry for such a newb question but all I was taught in school was how to write SQL queries so this is a bit over my head right now.

Comment: Perfect!  I didn't even know what lamda expressions were until now.  Very helpful thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell what that is, but that is LINQ using lamda expressions or method syntax.  follower may be a collection or it may be an Entity Framework database DbSet (like a table).  Or follower could be a database context and MenuItems is the DbSet.

Comment: If you are just starting out, I would recommend using Entity Frameworks (you can move to a different ORM later if you choose, but EF is the one that comes with .NET), and you use LINQ to make queries from it. You can use LINQ to make queries from lots of things (Xml, Collections, SQL Server, Entity Frameworks, etc.)

Comment: @RobertMcKee, yeah Follower is an EF DB (table), and MEnuItems are a table as well.  I did make this code based off watching tutorials, but when watching them there was no explanation of what exactly this was doing, and I like to know what I am doing, lol.  Thanks for your help.